# How to mock a single injection in a chain of injections - Arquillian

Tags: java, junit, dependency-injection, mockito, jboss-arquillian

How can a mock of a class that is in an injection chain? For example, **ServiceA** injects **ServiceB** that injects **ServiceC** (*ServiceA -> ServiceB -> ServiceC*).

In the Arquillian test I need to test **ServiceA** and mock **ServiceC**, which is called in my injection chain.

What I want is (*ServiceA -> ServiceB -> Mocked(ServiceC)*).

How can I do that using Arquillian?

```
@RunWith(Arquillian.class)
public class ServiceATest {

  @Inject
  private ServiceA serviceA;

  public void shouldTestServiceA() {
    //Mock ServiceC.execute();
    serviceA.execute();
  }

}

public class ServiceA {

  @Inject
  private ServiceB serviceB;

  public void execute() {
    serviceB.execute();
  }

}

public class ServiceB {

  @Inject
  private ServiceC serviceC;

  public void execute() {
    serviceC.execute();
  }

}

//needs to be mocked
public class ServiceC {

  public void execute() {

  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should consider following the explicit dependency principle via constructor injection.

And also, classes should depend on abstractions and not concretions.

`ServiceA` having a known dependency on `ServiceC` is an implementation concern and a code smell.

```
public class ServiceA {

    private ServiceB serviceB;

    public ServiceA(@Inject ServiceB serviceB) {
        this.serviceB = serviceB;
    }

    public void execute() {
        serviceB.execute();
    }
}

public interface ServiceB {
    void execute();
}

public interface ServiceC {
    void execute();
}
```

Now only `ServiceB` needs to be mocked and injected for the test.

The dependency of `ServiceB`'s implementation is no longer a concern of `ServiceA`